# How to run react-native project on two physical devices(expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to run my react-native project simultaneously on two physical devices I tried to scan the QR-code in two  different devices in which only my device runs that and other shows error.

Also I am using Expo cli so I can't use **react-native run-android-all** (issue fixed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5902))

Please help.

error on 2nd device screenshot:

[image]

working fine on 1st device screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You're gonna have to give us more info. tell us what you did and how you did it. Show us the errors.

Comment: sir do I need to provide the code here since it is running absolutely fine on my first device. screenshot added above

Comment: Works fine on my second device. You using LAN or tunnel?

Comment: okk I got it I was using LAN now I used tunnel worked fine on both devices. thanks for help